# For loop ffmpeg

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

Can someone help me creating a for loop for mutiple video files in directory structure

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx265 -c:a copy -x265-params crf=25 ouput.mp4
```

This works good for one video, but I'm lost how to do this in batch for multiple files

Comment: Similar question: [How do you convert an entire directory with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5784661)

Comment: Also using a for loop I think. This is meant for all files in an directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work for all files that end in ".mp4" in the current directory. The command will output to `new-filename.mp4` for each file. For example, if your file is `video1.mp4`, it will output a new file named `new-video1.mp4`

```
for i in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -c:v libx265 -c:a copy -x265-params crf=25 new-"$i"; done
```

Note:

- the first part `for i in *.mp4` needs to be unquoted.
- subsequent references to the variable `$i` should be quoted.
- don't forget `done` at the end
- if you need to work recursively, the loop would need to be more complex

Comment: Using Bash, recursive work wouldn't be that complex. Find input files with `**/*.mp4` (need `shopt -s globstar`), and construct output file names with `${i%/*}/new-${i##*/}`, or use `$(dirname "$i")/new-$(basename "$i")` for readability.